# How to assign/attach weight in edges of graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, networkx

I want to attach same or different weight with bunch of edges. But i do not find any function for this in NetworkX. If function is  available  in Networkx then what is it ,if not then suggest me how to attach weight with edges in python?
For examle: If i have some edge list ,which has no edges

```
edges=[(1,2),(1,4),(3,4),(4,2)]
```

then i want to attach same weight (1) with all edges.

expected output is : `weighted_edges=[(1,2,1),(1,4,1),(3,4,1),(4,2,1)]`

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't considered mapping a tuple to an integer? [(1,2) = 1 , (1,4) = 1 , (3,4) = 1 , (4,2)  = 1]

Answer (score 4):

The simplest version is to use `add_weighted_edges_from`

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,1),(1,4,1),(3,4,1),(4,2,1)])
G.edges(data=True)  #print out the edges with weight
>[(1, 2, {'weight': 1}),
 (1, 4, {'weight': 1}),
 (2, 4, {'weight': 1}),
 (3, 4, {'weight': 1})]
```

If you've already defined `edges`, then create the edges with their weights:

```
edges=[(1,2),(1,4),(3,4),(4,2)]
edges_with_weights=[(a,b,1) for (a,b) in edges]
H=nx.Graph()
H.add_weighted_edges_from(edges_with_weights)
H.edges(data=True)
> [(1, 2, {'weight': 1}),
(1, 4, {'weight': 1}),
(2, 4, {'weight': 1}),
(3, 4, {'weight': 1})]
```

Answer (score 1):

See networkx's [tutorial](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/tutorial.html#edge-attributes).

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=4.7 )
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3,{'weight':8})])
G[1][2]['weight'] = 4.7
G.edge[1][2]['weight'] = 4
```

In your example

```
G.add_edges_from(edges, weight=1)
```

Adds all the edges with a default weight of 1.